# SpriteKit Change Position after Touch

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am trying to change the position of a node after the half of the screen is tapped.
I got 3 exact Points where I want the node to move between them. To detect where the node is I created BOOL's.

My Code does not work right.If the Node is on Point 3, and I tap on the left side of the screen, it goes over to Point 1 and not to Point 2.
If I change in the Update Method to Node.position.x == (self.frame.size.width / 2), the Node only moves between Point 1 and Point 3.

```
@implementation MyScene {
BOOL Point1;
BOOL Point2;
BOOL Point3;
}

-(void)Node {
Node = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithTexture:Node1];
Node.size = CGSizeMake(50, 50);
Node.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, self.frame.size.height / 3);
Node.zPosition = 4;

[self addChild:Node];
} 

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self];

// If left half of the screen is touched
if (touchLocation.x < self.size.width / 2) {

    if(Point2 == YES){

        Node.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 3.5, self.frame.size.height / 3);
    }

    if(Point3 == YES){

        Node.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, self.frame.size.height / 3);
    }

}

// If right half of the screen is touched
if (touchLocation.x > self.size.width / 2) {

    if(Point1 == YES){

        Node.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 2, self.frame.size.height / 3);
    }

    if(Point2 == YES){

        Node.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width / 1.4, self.frame.size.height / 3);
    }

}

}

-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
/* Called before each frame is rendered */ 

if(Node.position.x >= (self.frame.size.width / 1.4)){

Point1 = true;
Point2 = false;
Point3 = false;

}

else if(Node.position.x >= (self.frame.size.width / 2)){

Point1 = false;
Point2 = true;
Point3 = false;

}

else if(Node.position.x >= (self.frame.size.width / 3.5)){

Point1 = false;
Point2 = false;
Point3 = true;

} }
```

Comment: check out your logic inside update function thats wrong your can't use == in ur situation check all condition with >= or =< or combine two >= or =<

Comment: I highly suggest you use if(Point1 == YES), it makes it harder to hack programs

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Are there still logic issues? As I said, if the Node is on Point 3, and the 'left touch', the node moves to Point 1 and not to Point 2.

Comment: Is there noone with an answer for me?

Comment: Why are you updating the bools in the update method? Just update everything in the one method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic in the Update Method was wrong. Whenever the Node's position was bigger than `self.frame.size.width / 2` Point2 was true. Here is the working code for the `UpdateMethod`:

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime {
/* Called before each frame is rendered */

if(Human.position.x > (self.frame.size.width / 1.6)){

    Point1 = false;
    Point2 = false;
    Point3 = true;
}

else if(Human.position.x == (self.frame.size.width / 2)){

    Point1 = false;
    Point2 = true;
    Point3 = false;
}

else if(Human.position.x < (self.frame.size.width / 3.0)){

    Point1 = true;
    Point2 = false;
    Point3 = false;
}
}
```